# incrementing key,value pair inside for loop iterating over dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I increment key value pair inside a for loop while iterating over dictionary in python?

```
for key,value in mydict.iteritems(): 
    if condition:
        #inc key,value
    #something to do
```

I have tried using `next(mydict.iteritems())` and `mydict.iteritems().next()` but in vain.

I am using python2.7.

EDIT - I know that forloop automatically increments the key,value pair. I want to manually increment to next pair ( Thus resulting in 2 increments).
Also I can't use continue because I want both the key value pair to be accessible at same time. So that when I increment, I have the current key value pair as well as the next. If I use continue, I lose access to current and only get next key,value pair.

Comment: What do you mean increment? WHY increment? For loop already loops through all key/value pairs, if you want to skip some key/value pairs based on condition use continue statement

Comment: i want to access the  next  key,value pair if some condition is true. So that both key value pair can be simultaneously accessed.

Comment: use `range(len(mydict-1))`

Comment: can you kindly explain how can `range(len(mydict-1))` can get me next key,value pair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
mydict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

items = mydict.iteritems()
for key,value in items:
    if key == 'b':  # some condition
        try:
            key,value = next(items)
        except StopIteration:
            break
    print(key, value)
```

Output:

```
('a', 1)
('c', 3)
```

Comment: Could have simply used `continue` to skip a certain key:
`mydict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

items = mydict.iteritems()
for key,value in items:
    if key == 'b':  # some condition
        continue
    print(key, value)
`

Comment: For Python3, iteritems() should replaced with items(), iterkeys() with keys() and itervalues() with values()
Ex: 
  
`Python 2.7 ---> mydict.iteritems()  `
`Python 3.x ---> mydict.items()`

Comment: And one more point to note. it should be
**key, value = next(iter(items))**

Comment: @ajaykools: `key, value = next(iter(items))` is not right and would never work.

Answer (score 1):

If you need simultaneous access to two key-value pairs use pairwise from [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).

```
from itertools import izip, tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to touch `key` and `value`:

```
skip = False
for key, value in mydict.iteritems(): 
    skip = not skip
    if skip:
        continue
    # something to do
```

If you need to have `key`/`value` from previous step, just store it:

```
skip = False
prev_item = None
for key, value in mydict.iteritems(): 
    skip = not skip
    if skip:
        prev_item = key, value
        continue
    # something to do. can access prev_item.
```

Comment: ... but the approach with ```tee``` recommened by @miles82 is probably more 'pythonic' solution.